# Using Autofac for WebForms and n-tier architecture

Tags: inversion-of-control, webforms, autofac

I am introducing unit testing to an existing webforms application. I am using Moq and Autofac. I'm trying to keep code changes to a minimum, but need to implement the unit testing.

So I have a presentation assembly, a business layer, and a data access layer. My business layer looks something like this:

```
public class EmployeeBL
{
    public Employee SelectById(int id)
    {
        return new EmployeeDA().SelectById(id);
    }
}
```

My Data access looks something like this:

```
public class EmployeeDA
{
    // unitOfWork defined in the constructor

    public Employee SelectById(int id)
    {
        return unitOfWork.Employees.Where(e => e.id == id);
    }
}
```

Autofac's webforms assembly allows you to declare a public property and specify web.config settings to automatically inject a dependency via HttpModule.  To test the `EmployeeBL`, I made the changes to web.config and declared `EmployeeDA` as a property:

```
// Modified for testing
[InjectProperties]
public class EmployeeBL
{
    // public property to allow Autofac property injection
    public IEmployeeDA EmployeeDA { get; set; }

    public Employee SelectById(int id)
    {
        return EmployeeDA.SelectById(id);
    }
}
```

This works for running the webforms application, but the problem is I need to unit test the business layer independently of a webforms instance. I would like to keep the `[InjectProperties]` attribute on my `EmployeeBL`, but I can't tell by the documentation how I can get the `EmployeeDA` to have its properties injected.

```
public class EmployeeBLTest
{
    private static IContainer { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Use my fake employeeDA for testing
        builder.RegisterType<FakeEmployeeDA>().As<IEmployeeDA>();

        // Something magical happens 
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SelectByIdTest(int id) { /* testing stuff */ }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

`builder.RegisterType<EmployeeDA>().AsSelf().PropertiesAutowired();`

see here:
http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/PropertyInjection

Comment: I should note I fixed the TestInitialize portion, but no, this does not work. The HTTPModule AttributedInjectionModule is responsible for injecting the correct dependency for the application, but builder.RegisterType<FakeEmployeeDA>().AsSelf().PropertiesAutoWired() does not inject FakeEmployeeDA for my IEmployeeDA in a unit test which does not run in an HTTPApplication instance.